# Excel DisplayAlerts Fails on Opening Workbook with GetObject

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use GetObject to open a workbook. I also want to disable alerts to update links during opening. It fails with GetObject:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Wb as Workbook
Set Wb = GetObject("C:\MyFile.xlsx")    ' <- update-links alert displayed here
```

Setting `Application.EnableEvents = False` before `GetObject` works as expected (i.e., prevents `Workbook_Open` in the opened book from running).

How can I disable update-links alert when using GetObject?

I'm using GetObject instead of Workbooks.Open, because GetObject cleanly opens the file as hidden, with barely a flicker on the front-end, which is what I need.

Comment: Good to know the benefit of GetObject - Thx

Comment: @TinBum I know, right!!!?? :)

Comment: Use ```Workbooks.Open``` while having ```Application.ScreenUpdating``` set to ```False``` in order to avoid flickering

Comment: @CristianBuse Ime, that creates far more visual noise, and often the opened worksheet become visible for a split second. Might be more an issue with remote files. GetObject performs much more cleanly for me. Btw, this question wasn't asking how to reduce flicker.

Comment: @johnywhy I know it was not the question, but you already answered the question and I only commented in case you weren't aware of ScreenUpdating. The comments section can be used to add things related to the question including links and so on but also notes regarding small details that do not belong in an answer. Good to know GetObject does less flickering.

Comment: @PeterMortensen You linked to an answer. But this is a question. The answer you linked to concerns pulling data from a closed workbook. That's irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

`Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False`